# Any Ruby API or Web Service to read scanned OMR sheets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

We are building a rails application that needs to process scanned OMR answer sheets and persist the results.

Is there any Ruby library to read scanned OMR sheets ? A paid web service or a desktop software which can be invoked through the command line will be good as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://ocrsdk.com/, it's a cloud-based OCR engine with web API. It provides [field-level recognition](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/quick-start/text-fields/) functionality for the data capture scenarios you describe as well as [checkmark](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/apireference/processCheckmarkField/) & [barcode](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/quick-start/barcode-sdk/) recognition. This service has a nice 90 days free trial without any upfront charges, so you don't have to pay anything until you go to production.

You may also find useful this [Ruby codesample](https://github.com/abbyysdk/ocrsdk.com/tree/master/Ruby) @ github (you'll need to sign up @ ocrsdk.com to receive API key). I was a part of the front-end development team for this service and can provide you more infon if necessary. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nikolay. I signed up for the trial version yesterday. I love the fact that it is REST based and has a ruby code sample ! I did not see much support for scanning bubble sheets though, which is what we specifically need. I tried using the online service that lets you upload a document and get the results. However uploading a sample bubble sheet gave an empty output. 

Do you know if the API has any specific support for processing bubble sheets ?

Comment: I'm not aware of a ready-to-go solution for your document type. And that's exactly where it comes to SDK. It allows you to pass an image with the checkmark coordinates and it returns you whether it's checked or not. Your part of the job is to work on layout description and tell SDK where to look for those checkmarks.

Comment: Got it ! A complete solution would have been great but the SDK is quite useful as well. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Does it support OMR?